# How do I access token value from array of Swift dictionaries

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, nested

I am trying to print/access the value from key "token" in the following (partial) JSON response.

So far I have tried:

```
print(User.tokens["token"])
```

Any idea how I can access this token? I am trying to say it to Keychain.

Thank you!

```
  User(tokens: [
  [
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.
  eyJfaWQiOiI2MDE2MzY5OGQzMGZjZTI0NjVhYTNiYTAiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTIwNjg1MDQsImV4cCI6MTYxMjUwMDU
  wNH0.uj7T-YcL8LCGQfBxwN9PBCObeGtpOpb5Ucz4vmMv_fQ", "_id": "60163698d30fce2465aa3ba1"
     ]
  ])
```

Comment: `tokens` is an array, it seems, with the first element being the dictionary. So, you first need to access that first element, then the key, `User.tokens[0]["token"]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to access to the array item first and then access to the dictionary as follows:

```
User.tokens[0]["token"]
```